# How can I pair all elements in a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

The goal is to create pairs/triplets/quartets from short lists, since these lists occur in a list of lists that I flatten. Since I want these elements to stay connected, I need a way to flatten the lists without losing the connection between the items in these particular lists.

In short, [a, b, c] needs to be converted to a-b-c. In theory long lists need to be handled too, but in reality only short lists will be relevant.

What I tried so far (which I know is horribly wrong):

```
create_pair([], Pair).

create_pair([H, H1|T], Pair):-
    NPair = H-H1, 
    create_pair(T, NPair).
```

This is just for the case of where the list has 2 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your pair/triplet/quartet/... by joining the two first items of the list and replacing it with your connection term until the whole list is processed:

```
create_ntets([H], H).
create_ntets([H,H1|T], NTet):-
  create_ntets([H-H1|T], NTet).
```

This procedure assumes there is no 0-tet.
Sample runs

```
?- create_ntets([a,b,c], Triplet).
Triplet = a-b-c

?- create_ntets([a,b,c,d], Quartet).
Quartet = a-b-c-d
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data structure you want to convert the short lists to doesn't really matter, you can just use `=../2` to convert the list to a term. Something like:

```
list_term(L,T) :- T =.. [ listlet | L ].
```

So evaluating `list_to_term( [a,b,c], T)` binds `T` as `listlet(a,b,c)` and evaluating `list_to_term( L , listlet(a,b,c,d) )` binds `L` as `[a,b,c,d]`.

See https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/list-to-term.pl for a runnable playground.